# How to use array_count_values() and mySQL to count value occurrence

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database, arrays

I have a mySQL database table with a column that corresponds to an image that has been voted on. The values are 001.jpg - 013.jpg. I need to figure out how many times each image has been voted for. I tried the following code, and got a count for 002.jpg, but none of the other images. There are at least 25 votes as of this moment. Here is the code I tried to use:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
mysql_select_db("club",$db);
$q = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM january");
$array = mysql_fetch_array($q);
$results = array_count_values($array);
         for each
         while (list ($key,$val) = each($results)) {
         echo "$key -> $val <br>";
         }
?>
```

I understand that array_count_values() is the way to count the occurrence of each vote, but all the examples I can find don't show how to pair this with mySQL. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need GROUP BY and COUNT():

```
SELECT image, COUNT(*) as votes FROM january GROUP BY image
```

This will return two columns: 1 for the image, and 1 for the number of votes for this image:

```
image     votes
001.jpg   1
002.jpg   32
...
```

Full code:

```
$db = mysql_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
mysql_select_db("club",$db);
$q = mysql_query("SELECT image, COUNT(*) as votes FROM january GROUP BY image");

$votes = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $votes[$row['image']] = $row['votes'];
}

// $votes is an array of 'image' => 'votes'

foreach($votes as $image => $count) {
    echo "$image: $count<br>";
}
```

Comment: This is great...thanks! I can't quite figure out an echo statement to get this written to the web page. Can you help with that?

Comment: `foreach($votes as $image => $count) { echo "$image: $count<br>"; }`

Comment: Very awesome...thanks! I appreciate everyone who took time to help out with this. I learn something new each time!