# How to use array_count_values() in the codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, arrays, codeigniter

I need to get the count of each countries by the database.

Here my coding is

```
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT country FROM list");
    echo"<pre>"; print_r($query->result());
```

The select query returns object as result and array_count_values need array in the parameter

So how can I use array_count_values to dynamically pass values in CodeIgniter.

Comment: The array_count_values function will not work with multidimensional arrays. You will most likely need to find another solutions or make your own

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT country, Count(*) FROM list GROUP BY country
```

Also you can find a full and detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867846/how-to-use-array-count-values-and-mysql-to-count-value-occurrence?rq=1)

Comment: This query will execute total number of distinct country in the table. But I need for India - 5, Mexico- 2 like wise i need

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    country,
    count(country) as `Total`
FROM list
GROUP BY country
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can following code

function fun_name() 
    {
        $this->db->where('id !=',0);// like this you can set conditions
        return $this->db->count_all_results('table_name');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `num_row()` function for this

```
  $this->db->select('country');
  $this->db->from('list');
  $query = $this->db->get();

  echo $query->num_rows(); // this will print the count of all countries
  echo"<pre>"; print_r($query->result()); // this can be used for fetching countries name(else)
```